# Swift NSTableView add Column programmatically -> Column-Title

Tags: swift, nstableview

When i add a Column programmatically to a NSTableView

```
    column = NSTableColumn()
    column.headerCell.setStringValue("Column-Title")  -> Here the Error
    outletTable.addTableColumn(column)
```

Xcode throws the Error

> '($T3) -> $T4' is not identical to 'String!'

Anybody had an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The type of Header-Cell is "AnyObject".
To set the Colum-Title use:

```
column.headerCell.setObjectValue("Column-Title")
```

Solved!